# How to get a certain word out of a string

Tags: java

So i need a help to find certain word in the given string. So I've made a string and used a for loop to get the word i want, but it doesn't seem to be working, I only want to get the `2019` out of the string.

```
public void wStart() throws Exception {
    String folder = "file/print/system/2019/12 - December";
    String[] folderSplit = folder.split("/");
    for (int i=3; i < folderSplit.length; i++) {
        String folderResult = folderSplit[i];
        System.out.println(folderResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can loop `folderSplit` and compare the value with `2019`. please change the `i` to 0 and `String folderResult = folderSplit[i];` to and if that check if the current item equals to 2019, something like `folderSplit[i] == "2019"`

Comment: "doesnt seem to be working" - It would help if you tell us what is happening right now. Then we do not need to guess or run it ourselves.

Comment: I don't understand what OP wants... do you want to remove 2019 from the string?

Answer (score 5):

If we only wish to get the year in a string with no other four digits number, we would be simply using this expression:

```
(\d{4})
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/iw7rCX/1/)

or we would add additional boundaries, such as:

```
\/(\d{4})\/
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/JWBlBK/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(\\d{4})";
final String string = "file/print/system/2019/12 - December";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Your pattern is not specific enough IMHO, because it would match _any_ four digits, _anywhere_ in the folder path.

Answer (score 3):

If the year would always be the second to last path element, then just access that element:

```
String folder = "file/print/system/2019/12 - December";
String[] parts = folder.split("/");
String year = parts[parts.length-2];
```

If instead the year could be any path element, then we can try fishing it out:

```
String year = folder.replaceAll(".*\\b(\\d{4})\\b.*", "$1");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this method, which I just added a statement that compares loop values with the string:

```
public static void wStart() throws Exception
{
 String folder = "file/print/system/2019/12 - December";
  String[] folderSplit = folder.split("/");
  for(int i = 3; i < folderSplit.length; i++)
   {
      if(folderSplit[i] == "2019"){
          String folderResult = folderSplit[i];
          System.out.println("Excepted "+folderResult);
      }else{
          String folderResult = folderSplit[i];
          System.out.println("Not Excepted "+folderResult);
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: I think in this answer dnt need any kind of explanation just a basic, I am just add compare statement that compares loop value to the string

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The modification is, then, incorrect. To compare strings in Java, use `.equals()`, since the operator `==` only tests for identity. (By stating in simple sentences the change that was made, you save people the time of mentally `diff`ing your code & the OP code. Explanations in prose, if not essential (though, I'd argue they are) are at the very least considerate to others.)  Also, to avoid confusion, I believe you meant to say `accepted`, not `excepted` (which implies the opposite).